# How to remove '=-inf' from a data frame with Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some files with `=-inf` cells. I have been trying to remove it with:

`.replace(np.inf, 0).replace(np.nan,0)`

However it stays there, I also check if the data frame has any infinity number with:

`df.isnull().values.any()
np.all(np.isfinite(df))`

But none of them finds =-inf or NA.

How could I replace this kind of issue with Python?

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
Download the actual csv file here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ol_DfiUbkybLx-ksne3rszyODTARzMJM/view?usp=sharing

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
labels = np.array(df['class'])

features= df.drop('class', axis = 1)
feature_list = list(features.columns)
features = np.array(df)

clf= RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=20)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, features, labels, cv=10)
```

Comment: Please show your code and example data we could use to reproduce

Comment: @anonjnr I have updated the issue, I added the CSV file and also the code, with this you are able to reproduce.

Comment: I think you need `df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0)`

Comment: because negative inf are not replaced

Comment: @jezrael make it the answer, bc that's it

Comment: @jezrael thank you a lot, you are completely right, I don't know why I didn't think about that. Yes, Please make it an answer so I can make your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is negative infinite, so need replace it:

```
df = df.replace(-np.inf, 0)
```

More general solution is:

```
df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.NINF` is negative infinity. Simply replace it with 0.

```
df = df.replace(np.NINF, 0)
```